# Function of "verde" in "Me gusta el verde de tu ojos"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, sustantivos, categorías-gramaticales

Is the word "verde" in this sentence considered to have a funcion of an adjective or a name?

> Me gusta el **verde** de tu ojos.

I personally think it's of a name because it's making the word "verde" look like a noun but I'm not sure. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the DRAE (the dictionary of the Royal Spanish Academy)

20. m. Colorante o pigmento utilizado para producir el color verde.

So it is a noun

Comment: Two additions: 1. If noun, should always be preceded by article. 2. If noun, always is male.

Answer (score 2):

*Verde* here is an [*adjetivo sustantivado*](http://www.gramaticas.net/2012/05/ejemplos-de-adjetivos-sustantivados.html) (i.e., an adjective that performs the function of a noun). You are not referring to a coloring (colorante o pigmento), but the color itself, and it is actually doing the job of a noun.

In English you do this all the time. In Spanish it is way less common, but it happens.

DRAE's entry for [sustantivar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YpdenDZ) leads to [nominalizar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QaR6aI9), which unfortunately is too general, but touches the concept.

Comment: I've been looking a more detailed, *official* source. As soon as I find one, I'll edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we are omitting a word here:

> Me gusta el (**color**) verde de tus ojos.

*color* is the noun, and green is characterising the noun, so *verde* is an adjective.